# How to install linux to some physical computers efficiently

Tags: installation, linux-distributions

I want to build a distributed computational environments.
I'm going to use Ubuntu Server as OS.

How to install Ubuntu Server to some(15) physical computers efficiently.

The most better technique is following where I found.

> How to create a network bootable installer
>   http://www.fefe.de/netboot/how-to-netboot-installer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/hppa/preseed-using.html) to generate an install image that installs exactly what you need. In particular, `d-i preseed/late_command` allows you to execute arbitrary commands. [Here's a guide I've written on askubuntu.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29121/guide-to-particulars-in-customizing-ubuntu-installer/29632#29632)

Comment: Thank you kindly, I'm going to make custom install image.

Answer (score 0):

I think that https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html is a guide for installation on multiple computers. Also, I think that Ubuntu Server cloud installation: http://www.ubuntu.com/business/cloud/overview is worth a try if your purpose is to make distributed environment.